# How to apply matplotlib dateformatter to pandas datetime64[ns] index?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Matplotlib appears to misinterpret a Pandas datetime64[ns] index.  My MVCE shows some current dates being interpreted as being in 1970.  Is it simply not possible to use the `mpl.dates` formatters with pandas dates?  `ax.get_figure().autofmt_xdate()` works fine, but returns the whole verbose date string.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
from pandas import Timestamp
print(f"pd:{pd.__version__} mpl:{mpl.__version__}")

df = pd.DataFrame({'Hourly Total': 
 {Timestamp('2022-04-28 11:00:00-0700', tz='Canada/Pacific'): 0.0012916667166666667,
  Timestamp('2022-04-28 12:00:00-0700', tz='Canada/Pacific'): 0.00383333365,
  Timestamp('2022-04-28 13:00:00-0700', tz='Canada/Pacific'): 0.00383333365,
  Timestamp('2022-04-28 14:00:00-0700', tz='Canada/Pacific'): 0.00383333365},
})

ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
formatter = mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

[image: Plot showing wrong dates]

Comment: A workaround (but not a solution) is to manually override the ticklabels, with `ax.set_xticklabels([pandas_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for pandas_datetime in df.index])`

Answer (score 7):

This is a problem of the Pandas bar plotting function. If you change the `DateFormatter` to a `StrMethodFormatter` to check what values are passed, you can see that it just receives the scalar index (starting from 0) of the bars you are plotting:

```
# Here 'x' is the value used to format the tick labels.
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x} {pos}'))
```

Which shows:

[image: data passed to the formatter by Pandas]

Consequently, the `DateFormatter` is trying to convert 0, 1, 2, and 3 to a date, which gives the Epoch 1970-1-1 UTC. Unfortunately, there is no easy way around that using the default formatters provided by `matplotlib`, since they will always receive the wrong data.

**Solution 1**
As your comment suggests, one solution is to simply change the `xticklabels` manually.

```
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

**Solution 2**
Use matplotlib instead of Pandas for the plotting. In this case, also note that `DateFormatter` ignores the timezone of your dates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pet
import pytz

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df.index, df['Hourly Total'], width=0.03)
# Notice here we do need the timezone.
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.dates.HourLocator(interval=1, tz=pytz.timezone('Canada/Pacific')))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d %H:%M', tz=pytz.timezone('Canada/Pacific')))
f.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib version]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you know whether there is an open issue on pandas-dev I can follow? Or does a new issue need to be raised?

Comment: Actually, if you change the above MVE to `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.dates.HourLocator())` (and comment out the `set_major_formatter` bit) you do see correct (non-epoc) dates, so Pandas is passing the values through...?

Comment: @rwb I belive this is because `DateLocator` needs different values. It works by taking the minimum and maximum values in the x axis to derive the plot ticks with their difference. The formatter instead gets the `x` and `pos` value of the bars, which are actually just scalars when using the pandas bar plotting function. I could find this [old issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1918) which has still just workarounds.