# Using Grouper to group dataframe by various timeframes and charting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here's a Python program which does the following:

- Makes an API call to treasury.gov to retrieve data
- Stores the data in a Pandas dataframe

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

date = '1900-01-01'

transaction_type = 'Withdrawals'
transaction_catg = 'Interest on Treasury Securities'

page_size = 10000

url = 'https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/dts/deposits_withdrawals_operating_cash'

url_params = f'?filter=record_date:gt:{date},transaction_type:eq:{transaction_type},transaction_catg:eq:{transaction_catg}&page[size]={page_size}'

response = requests.get(url + url_params)

result_json = response.json()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

df = pd.DataFrame(result_json['data'])

df['record_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.record_date)

df['transaction_today_amt'] = pd.to_numeric(df['transaction_today_amt']) 

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
plt.ion()
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Group using `strftime`

Let's group by month using `strftime`.

```
items = df.groupby(df['record_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['transaction_today_amt'].sum()

plt.figure()
plt.bar(x=items.index, height=items.values)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]

The graph looks pretty good. However, there are some drawbacks:

- scrunched x-axis labels
- does not use Grouper

## Group using `Grouper`

```
items = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='record_date', freq='M'))['transaction_today_amt'].sum()

plt.figure()
plt.bar(x=items.index, height=items.values)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]

Now the x-axis labels look good and we're using Grouper. However, the columns are thin lines.

## Group using `Grouper`. Use pandas plot method.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='record_date', freq='M'))['transaction_today_amt'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Now we're using `Grouper` and the column lines are thick. However, the x-axis labels include time and are pretty scrunched.

## Question

What's a good way setup this chart so that Grouper is being used without the drawbacks shown in the above approaches?

I'd like to use Grouper because it allows for easily grouping by arbitrary timeframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example (using `pd.Grouper`) the width of your bin corresponds to a *day*, hence the thin bins. An easy workaround would be to set the width of your bin to 27 (avoiding overlap for february):

```
items = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='record_date', freq='M'))['transaction_today_amt'].sum()

plt.figure()
plt.bar(x=items.index, height=items.values, width=27)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Sent you a tip on PayPal 

Comment: Much appreciated! Regarding the other solutions, formatting the x tick labels will require additional steps. For 1) you'll have to convert items index to date before applying a dateformatter/locator. For 3) see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72071077/how-to-apply-matplotlib-dateformatter-to-pandas-datetime64ns-index)